# scheme function to call a procedure n times

Tags: scheme, guile

Does scheme have a function to call a function n times. I don't want map/for-each as the function doesn't have any arguments. Something along the lines of this :-

```
(define (call-n-times proc n)
        (if (= 0 n)
            '()
            (cons (proc) (call-n-times proc (- n 1)))))

(call-n-times read 10)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SRFI 1](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-1/srfi-1.html) has a `list-tabulate` function that can build a list from calling a given function, with arguments 0 through `(- n 1)`. However, it does not guarantee the order of execution (in fact, many implementations start from `(- n 1)` and go down), so it's not ideal for calling `read` with.

In Racket, you can do this:

```
(for/list ((i 10))
  (read))
```

to call `read` 10 times and collect the result of each; and it would be done left-to-right. But since you tagged your question for Guile, we need to do something different.

Luckily, Guile has [SRFI 42](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-42/srfi-42.html), which enables you to do:

```
(list-ec (: i 10)
  (read))
```

Comment: Cool. I'll use one of my own for now. I wonder why they left it from the standard. Good to know that it wasn't something too obvious :)

Comment: @Himanshu Scheme, at least in the earlier versions, is a pretty minimal language.  The fact that this was a pretty easy utility to write is a good justification for leaving it out of the language. "It's only three lines, and it's easy to write?  We don't need to put it in the spec." :)

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor Yes sounds reasonable. I find Scheme's minimality to be the most attractive features.

Answer (score 0):

Implementing [tail-recursion modulo cons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call#Tail_recursion_modulo_cons) optimization by hand, to build the resulting list with O(1) extra space:

```
(define (iterate0-n proc n)   ; iterate a 0-arguments procedure n times
  (let ((res (list 1)))       ; return a list of results in order
    (let loop ((i n) (p res))
      (if (< i 1)
        (cdr res)
        (begin
          (set-cdr! p (list (proc)))
          (loop (- i 1) (cdr p)))))))
```

This technique first (?) described in [Friedman and Wise's TR19](http://www.cs.indiana.edu/cgi-bin/techreports/TRNNN.cgi?trnum=TR19).